# React router open page using URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new in react programming. Trying to solve issue my self but, stuck on following issue.

I have following react router code.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Main extends Component {

render() {   
        return ( 
    <Router>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Content} />   
       <Route path='/user/:id' component={User} /> 
       <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
     </Switch>  
    </Router>
    );
}

export default Main
```

In content there are list of users with their photo. If  i click on person photo it will redirect me to particular user.

I wrote my code like:

```
<Link to={'/user/' + userItem.id}>
     <img className="useritem-img" src={userItem.photo} alt={userItem.tagline}/>
</Link>
```

It will open User Component properly with new URL like: http://localhost:3000/user/457365 on photo click.

But, when copy and paste same url in new tab it will not open. May be i am wrong some where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I am getting following error when i open that page:

> Cannot GET /user/457365

I am not using create-react-app just simple react application.

Following is my server.js

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        open('http://localhost:' + port);
    }
})
```

Comment: Is this using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: But dont trhow any error in your console?

Comment: are you using a server side language or just react js app ?

Comment: So, what do you see when you copy-paste the url in the new tab? Your problem probably has to do with the fact that the server is also trying to handle the routing...

Comment: When you copy and paste the whole url into the browser then the browser asks your server if the file with such route exists on the server. Of course it doesn't because you are creating SPA. So your server needs to return index.html to any incoming requests.

Comment: I am using just react js app. Not using create-react-app

Comment: Whatever server it is you're using make sure all the routes respond with your main page index.

Comment: @apokryfos except for the "static" assets, of course ;-) (i.e. js files, css files, images, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting that error that means that the server is trying to handle the routing. Therefore you should make sure that the server allows the SPA to handle the routing.

For instance, if you are using `express`, you probably want to do something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('/api/whatever', (req,res) => {
  // Whatever your api does
});

// Allow the SPA to take care of the routing
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed after adding following in webpack. `output: {
    publicPath: '/'
},

devServer: {\
    historyApiFallback: true
}`

Comment: @ketan you never mentioned the fact that you were using webpack dev-server. In fact, you explicitly said that you were using your own express server ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Anywyas, I'm happy to know that you found the issue.

Comment: @ketan given the amount of information that you provided I think that my answer should be marked as accepted. Because the issue actually was the fact that the server was preventing the client from handling the routing.